# Does C++ remake a variable defined in a loop?

Tags: c++, loops, memory

When a variable is declared inside a loop in C++, does C++ remake the variable in each iteration of the loop? I mean, does it reallocate memory for another `num` variable? So if the loop iterates 5 times, do you get 5 separate `num` variables with their own unique values? Is it a better practice to declare a variable before the loop starts, even if that variable will only be used inside the loop? What if for instance I want to use the variable as a counter or placeholder?

```
// is this better code?
// int num;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  int num;
  // do stuff with num
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Yes, if `num` is definition inside the loop, then it will represent a different variable every time the loop runs. Each time control passes through its definition, it will be newly initialized (if at all) and each time an iteration of the loop ends, it will be destroyed.

A variable should normally be declared in the narrowest scope possible. So if `num` does not need to retain its value from one iteration to the next, it should normally be defined inside the loop. If it does need to retain its value from one iteration to the next, it must be defined outside the loop.

There are some exceptions to this stylistic best practice, such as when the initialization is expensive.

Answer (score 6):

The compiler *may* optimize memory usage so the variable is only physically allocated one time and then reused on each loop iteration.  But,  in general, **YES**, scoping rules require each loop iteration to operate on a distinct instance of the variable.  And in the case of complex types, like classes/structs, that means calling a constructor and destructor on the variable on each loop iteration.

Answer (score 4):

It is a new variable. You can easily convince yourself of that by the fact that this compiles:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  const int num = i;
  // do stuff with num
}
```

If it were really the same variable, how are we assigning something new to a constant variable?

As for whether it is more efficient somehow, you should remember that C++ has a very good optimizing compiler. There's no real "cost" associated with a stack variable. A simple integer assignment clearly doesn't have any side effects so it's trivial for the compiler to reuse the same space. If you don't need the variable outside the loop it's better to declare it inside the loop.

I suggest using https://gcc.godbolt.org/ to look at the assembly generated for a few small functions with and without optimizations, it will give you a feel for what the compiler can easily optimize away.

Answer (score 2):

In the situation you've outlined, the C++ standard specifies that a new instance of the variable gets constructed at the beginning of the loop, and destroyed at the end of the loop.

What actually happens, when you get down to the nitty gritty of it, is besides the point. A C++ implementation is permitted to implement this in any manner it wants to, as long as the observable result is as specified by the C++ standard.

Here you just have a plain, garden variety `int`. Although it is formally constructed, and destroyed, as I described, nothing of substance really happens when the variable is constructed and destroyed. C++ does not require a newly-constructed `int`, in local scope, to be initialized to any particular value. So a typical C++ implementation, in this case, would simply assign this `int` to some pigeonhole in memory, somewhere, and just use it for every loop iteration.

But, if you were to replace this `int` with a more fleshed out object, with a formal constructor, you will see that the object's constructor will be obediently invoked at the beginning of every loop iteration, and the object's destructor will be obediently invoked at the end of the loop iteration (or when the execution thread leaves the loop's scope).